# Not sure which character it is

Tags: php

I'm following a PHP tutorial, but I've come across a chracter and I have no idea what it is.

Here's a picture of it http://prntscr.com/7wktf6

Please tell me what it is and how to get it

Answer (score 1):

That is the "&" symbol,  a.k.a. "and" or ampersand

In the picture you took, two ampersands (&) next to each other in a logic statement means "and". Example,

`(0 == 1 && 2 == 2)` and `(0 == 1 && 2 == 3)`

evaluiate to **false** because one or more of the statments on either side of the "&&" is false. While,

`(0 == 0 && 1 == 1)`

evaluates to **true** because they are *both* true.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) is more information on the matter.